# cannot commit or push using egit (guess: issues with secure storage area)

Tags: eclipse, security

I can commit/push from bash shell using git. However, I cannot commit/push using eclipse/egit. I get pop up error " ssh://xxx@scm.internal.yyy.com/home/git/cbm.git: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many authentication failures for xxx"

I believe secure storage area is creating the problems. I use multiple machines (desktop and laptop) in office to access the repo and recently I changed the passwords. I believe this is causing issues egit/eclipse accessing the repo because of the secure storage setup in eclipse.

Is there anyway, I can reset/delete the secure storage in eclipse. I tried few things (based on https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425672):

1. restored default in eclipse preferences: General/Security/Secure Storage and in
2. General/Network Connections/SSH2

I am on eclipse Kepler

Answer (score 0):

deleted the folder ~user/.eclipse.
I think it stores all the temporary settings. working on centos.
staying away from setting up secure storage after restarting eclipse

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway, I can reset/delete the secure storage in eclipse.

This is now available by going to Preferences -> General -> Security -> Secure Storage and then pressing the *Delete* button.

You don't need to blow away your other settings to clear the remembered passwords.

[image]